# How can I cast objects that don't inherit each other?

Tags: java, object, casting

I have 2 different classes with different fields and a class which has all the fields of both classes. Is there any way to cast the object in to two separate objects?

```
class A{
    private int a;
    private int b;
}

class B{ 
    private int a;
    private int b;
}
```

If object `D` have all the properties of A and B classes, Is there any way to cast them separately?

Comment: No, not possible. There's no multiple inheritance in Java. Need to refactor using interfaces.

Comment: **No.** Here if both have common properties, they might have some relationship. Like, `B extends A`

Comment: d extends A where A already extends b. In that case you can have d,which has all the properties of A and B. You need to modify something like this. If you want to make B independent to A, then class can extend only one class. So this won't be possible.

Comment: What about using interface instead of class for `A` and `B`? So your target object can implement both interfaces `C implements A, B`

Comment: @MincongHuang I wouldn't recommend sharing interface based on fields...

Comment: Hint: start by learning about proper **terminology**. You are using terms like *casting* in a very strange way. Same for *properties*, and *objects*. So, first of all, these are **fields**, not attributes/properties. And by casting you mean re-use?

Comment: Casting (of non-primitive types) does not do any kind of automatic conversion. There is no way to convert an object of type `A` to type `B` using a cast.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting take place from child to parent (downcast) or vise versa (upcast):

```
class A extends B
B b = (B)(new A());
```

or in case of interfaces:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> myArrayList = (ArrayList)myList;
```

Be careful when casting - if casting is not possible, you'll receive `Exception`!

In your case, *mapping* is what you're looking for. You simply need a mapper.

For example:

```
public class AToBMapper {
    public static A fromB(B b) {
        A a = new A();
        a.setA(b.getA());
        a.setB(b.getB());
        return a;
    }

    public static B fromA(A a) {
        //fill in
    }
}
```

Comment: not only Java allows both downcast and upcast, they are both usefull

Comment: There are utilities as `BeanUtils` that can help `BeanUtils.copyProperties(origin, target);`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I think it's ok now, but feel free to edit

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera yes there are, but I don't want to recommend external library. If I had to, I'd recommend MapStruct :)

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I disagree. A *downcast* is most often a symptom of bad design.

Answer (score 3):

As complement of the very good answer of xenteros, you could also use library to do it if you have to repeat this task for many classes.

Spring, apache-commons and many others provides utility class to copy field by field which one of them that have the same name and type between two classes:

For example with `ModelMapper` :

```
  ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
  A a = new A(....);
  B b = mapper.map(a, B.class)
```

Some libraries are very efficient (Selma, MapStruct, JMapper). Most of them generating the code at compile time
Others are less efficient. 
You should so evaluate this point,  the size of objects to map and the mapping frequency before generalizing the use of this kind of library.

Comment: MapStruct is my favorite, because it doesn't use reflection - it just generates sources according to the interface. Disclaimer: I contribute to MapStruct but just to the examples, when I struggle to find an example on my own :)

Comment: The famous advantage of MapStruct :) I had to use it at a time but finally I never had the opportunity because of compatibility problem.