# How can i zip multiple pdf files in Primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to zip multiple pdf files which are selected in the data-table and let the user download them.

Here is XHTML;

```
<p:commandLink id="print_orders" 

        value="Print Selected Orders" ajax="false" 
        onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startPrint, stopPrint);"  
        styleClass="button button--ujarak button--border-thin button--text-medium download"
        style="text-align: center;  float:none; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; padding: 0.05em 0.1em;" >
                            
        <p:fileDownload value="#{printOrdersManagedBeanSAP.printsAction()}" />

</p:commandLink>
```

Let me clarify managedbean side;

purchaseOrder object includes PO_NUMBER() I generate pdf document (pdfDoc) as ByteArrayOutputStream from SAP with PO_NUMBER(). With for loop I tried to produce zip file includes pdf documents as much as the selected column. By the way I'm not sure I did it right.

With "return (StreamedContent) output;" code block I tried to return zip file but I get "java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent" exception. I tried to convert ZipOutputStream to StreamedContent because of <p:fileDownload> Primefaces tag.

Can you help me with how to fix this problem?

```
 public StreamedContent printsAction()
{
    if(!termsAgreed)
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('warningDialog').show();");
    else
    {
        if (getSelectedPurchaseOrders() != null && !getSelectedPurchaseOrders().isEmpty()) {
            
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream zipFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("PO_Reports.zip"));
                ZipOutputStream output   = new ZipOutputStream(zipFile);
                
                for (PurchaseOrderSAP purchaseOrder : getSelectedPurchaseOrders()) {
                    
                    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfDoc = purchaseOrderSAPService.printOrder(selectedPurchaseOrder.getPO_NUMBER());
                    
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(purchaseOrder.getPO_NUMBER());
                    output.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                    
                    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfDoc.toByteArray());
                    
                    IOUtils.copy(targetStream, output);
                    output.closeEntry();
                }
                
                output.finish();
                output.close();
                return (StreamedContent) output;
                
                
            }       
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                    System.out.println("error when generating...");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Zipping multiple pdf files is the same as zipping multiple txt files and NOT a PrimeFaces thing but pure java. The error you get woupd also be given when sending one zipped pdf or a plain non-zipped pdf or txt file. Try...  And check the PF showcase on how to use StreamedContent. Casting != converting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solutions to these problems. Maybe this solution will help someone else. I would be grateful for any contribution on the new solution.

```
public StreamedContent printsAction() {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
    InputStream stream = null;
    if (!termsAgreed) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('warningDialog').show();");
    } else {
        if (getSelectedPurchaseOrders() != null && !getSelectedPurchaseOrders().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                if (zipBytes() != null) {
                    bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(zipBytes()); // Firstly I zip every PDF doc with zipBytes() method
                    stream = bis;
                    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/zip", "PO_Reports.zip",StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                    return file;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                    if (stream != null) {
                        stream.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private byte[] zipBytes() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfDoc = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
    DataInputStream pdfDocIs = null;
    byte[] result = null;
    try {
        for(PurchaseOrderSAP purchaseOrder : getSelectedPurchaseOrders()) {
            pdfDoc = purchaseOrderSAPService.printOrder(purchaseOrder.getPO_NUMBER()); // PDF document comes from SAP as ByteArrayOutputStream
            pdfDocIs = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfDoc.toByteArray()));
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("PO_Report_" + purchaseOrder.getPO_NUMBER() + ".pdf");
            zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            zos.write(toByteArray(pdfDocIs)); // Secondly in order to zip PDF doc i convert it to Byte Array with toByteArray method
        }
        zos.close();
        result =  baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (baos != null) {
                baos.close();
            }
            if (pdfDoc != null) {
                pdfDoc.close();
            }
            if (zos != null) {
                zos.close();
            }
            if (pdfDocIs != null) {
                pdfDocIs.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream in) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    byte[] result = null;
    int len;
    // read bytes from the input stream and store them in buffer
    try {
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            // write bytes from the buffer into output stream
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        result = os.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you create the zip two times?

Comment: I thought I created one zip file with zos and put the pdfs into zos. Which is the second zip file?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot simply **cast** a `ZipOutputStream` to `StreamedContent` as they don't have a parent child relation. See [How can I cast objects that don't inherit each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409944/how-can-i-cast-objects-that-dont-inherit-each-other).

You should **convert** your `InputStream` (not the output stream) to streamed content. See for example https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml

So, you need to do something like:

```
DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                .name("PO_Reports.zip")
                .contentType("application/zip")
                .stream(() -> yourInputStream)
                .build();
```